# Function in javascript is not being executed when being called in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, forms

I am trying to execute a function in Javascript by clicking on an image in my website. The problem is that the console does not show ANYTHING. I do not know the error.

The function has to submit a form by using a post request.

This is the code of my image and form  in HTML:

```
<div class="team"> 
        <img class="teamInfo" src="images/leaderboard.png">  
        <p class= "createT"> Create a Team </p>
        <p class= "chooseC"> Choose a Charity </p>
        <p class= "enter"> Enter Team Member's Email</p>
        <p class= "upload">Upload your Company<br>or Team's Logo</p>

        <!-- added action tag solved the 405 error : "post method not allowed"-->
     <form id="create_team_form"  action="" method ="post" >
            <textarea class= "teamName" type="text" id="teamName" name ="teamName"  size ="25" maxlength ="60"/>Team Name
            </textarea>
            <textarea class= "companyName" type="text" id="companyName"  name ="companyName"  size   ="25" maxlength   = "60" value="Company Name"/> Company Name
            </textarea>
            <textarea class= "teamDescription"  type="text" id="teamDescription"  name ="teamDescription"    size ="25"    maxlength = "60" value="Team Description"/>     Team Description
            </textarea>
            <textarea class= "email" type="text" id="email"  name ="email"  size ="25"   maxlength = "60" value="emails"/>   Emails</textarea>
            <textarea class= "searchCharity"  type="text" id="charityName" name ="charityName  "  size ="25"      maxlength = "60"/>  Search for a Charity
            </textarea>
            <p class="click"> Click the charity's name to select who your team will run for!</p>
     </form>   
     <img class="img-box" src="images/imgBox.png" alt=""/>
     <img class="greenButton" src="images/greenbutton.png" alt="" onClick="createTeam();"/>
</div>
```

This is my function in JavaScript:

```
function createTeam(){

    var teamN= document.getElementById("teamName").value;
    var companyName =document.getElementById("companyName").value; //maybe not, tae it off.
    var charityName = document.getElementById("charityName").value;



    if((teamN.trim() == "") || (companyName.trim() == "") || (charityName.trim() == ""))
    {
        alert("You did not fill the team Name  or companyName, Please enter with a name");

    }else{

        $('#create_team_form').submit(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                         var sessionID = $.cookie("sessionID")
                         $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:9000/team/?sessionID="+sessionID,
                                data: $(this).serialize(),
                                success: function(msg) {
                                    $.cookie("teamID",msg.teamID)
                                    $.cookie("sessionID",sessionID)
                                }
                                });
                         });
        }
}
   function openEditTeamPage(){

       window.location.href='editTeam.html';

    }
```

The console does not show anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've wrapped all your code in a function for some strange reason, do you actually call that function anywhere, otherwise why would it work ?

Comment: Does the `alert` show up if you don't fill in the team name or company name?

Comment: Also, how do you submit a form with only `textarea` elements and no submit button ?

Comment: What do you see when you set a breakpoint on the code in question using the debugger built into your browser, and step through the code? It's 2014, there's almost never any need for `alert` debugging.

Comment: Note: Your HTML is invalid. You are self-closing the `<textarea>` elements as well as having closing `</textarea>` tags.

Comment: @adeneo I call the function in here: <img class="greenButton" src="images/greenbutton.png" alt="" onClick="createTeam();"/>

Comment: so every time you click that image, you bind the event handlers an do all that crap ?

Comment: what is the problem with textare elements. I try with submit button.

Answer (score 0):

There are two method signatures for using jQuery's `.submit()` method.

See this line from the docs:

> Description: Bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event, **or** trigger that event on an element.

[emphasis mine]
[found here](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

When you provide a function to the `.submit()` method like so `.submit(function() {});` It will add that function as an event handler to that form's `submit` event. However, it does not actually **trigger** the `submit` event. The `submit` event will only be triggered if you provide no arguments to `.submit()`.

So,

```
$('#create_team_form').submit()
```

will submit the form, but

```
$('#create_team_form').submit(function() {
 // code 
});
```

will only add an event handler to the form's submit event. The form doesn't get submitted in the latter example.

You don't need the `.submit()` at all, because you're not actually submitting your form—you're sending the data manually. See [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/G4l47O69ocDugUMjfiCx?p=preview) for an example of how to achieve this.

Comment: How about this one: -> $('formName').on('submit', function(e){            })

Comment: That's still adding a handler to the `submit` event. In order for that function to get called, a `submit` event has to be triggered. In your current code the `submit` event is not fired. You either have to call `.submit()` on the form itself OR add a submit button to the form and let that trigger the `submit` event.

Comment: It was supposed to work. But it does not do anything. :/  I am gonna try again. So, I can choose your answer.

Comment: Did you try the code in the plunkr example? You might want to avoid `.submit()` altogether.